# react-map-gl add background color outside polygon

Tags: polygon, highlight, react-map-gl

I am using react-map-gl and I want to somewhat put a background color outside the polygon that was created. I tried using multiple `<Layers />` but it looks like it does not accept multiple instances.

```
<Source id="polygons-source" type="geojson" data={geojsonData}>
  <Layer
    id="polygons"
    type="line"
    source="polygons-source"
    paint={{ 
      'line-color': 'red', 
      'line-opacity': 1, 
      'line-width': 1
    }}
  />
  <Layer
    id="polygons"
    type="fill"
    source="polygons-source"
    paint={{ 
      'fill-color': 'transparent',
      'fill-opacity': 0.5
    }}
  />
  <Layer
    id="polygons"
    type="background"
    source="polygons-source"
    paint={{ 
      'background-color': 'gray', 
      'background-opacity': 0.5
    }}
  />
</Source>
```

It just show me the first instance of the `<Layer />` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about the layer question, you need to have different id for them to appear. you can also stack them to different orders: using the `beforeId` property of the `<Layer>` component.

Second, to highlight only the polygon you can use the mask function from `@turf/turf` package.

```html
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

const poly = turf.polygon(geojsonData.features[0].geometry.coordinates);
const worldMask= turf.polygon([
  [
    [-180, -90],
    [180, -90],
    [180, 90],
    [-180, 90],
    [-180, -90],
  ],
]);

var masked = turf.mask(poly, mask);

<Source id="polygons-source" type="geojson" data={masked}>
    <Layer
      id="polygons"
      type="fill"
      source="polygons-source"
      paint={{ 'fill-color': 'gray', 'fill-opacity': 0.5 }}
    />
</Source>
```